# Additional Memory?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ram

I am trying to install 16.04 LTS on an old Dell currently running 12.04 and Windows XP. I was told to upgrade memory to 2 Gigs and am wondering if new memory sticks should go in slots marked #1 and old memory should be moved back to slots marked #2 for better performance. On re-installation I plan to erase the Windows partition and devote entire 80 GIG hardrive/32 bit to Ubuntu 16.04. Does this sound correct or should I stall new memory in slots marked #2? The installed memory was 512 MB and will be inadequate. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it isn't about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Given you talk about really, really, really, old hardware (Hints: 80GB Hard disk, 512MB RAM... Probably P-IV class machines), you really should figure out first whether your motherboard supports RAM sticks larger than 512MB.  I'm not even sure you bought the correct type of RAM.

As for the slot you have to use:  In the best case this machine supports dual-channel RAM, but since you almost definitely have two different types of RAM sticks, it will switch to single-channel RAM.  You have no way of avoiding that (One stick: single channel / Two sticks with different specs: single channel).  Conclusion:   it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks.Im sure the sticks are compatible,at least from Dell website, it says computer is not capable of upgrade above 2GB so I got two more sticks,1GB a piece,  and will leave the old ones in

Comment: Depending on how lucky you are, that existing 512MB may be detected too.   If not, remove it.  Furthermore, refer to the manual of your computers manufacturer to see how to best place RAM.  Often it is colour coded (as in two blue, two black slots).  Most of the time, you'll put two identical sticks in the same colour slots.  Alas, it's not standardized.  Only the manual of your machine can tell you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you are installing ubuntu :). As long as both sticks of memory are the same size and speed it doesn't really matter which stick goes where